# Standardize Dropdown's Selected Handlebars Helper

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I'm facing the following challenge building some dropdowns with Handlebars.

Instead of modeling the dropdown's select this way:

```
<div class="form-floating col-3">
            <select name="sport" class="form-select" id="floatingSelect">
                <option {{selectedSport sport 'all'}} value="all">All</option>
                <option {{selectedSport sport 'Hiking'}} value="Hiking">Hiking</option>
                <option {{selectedSport sport 'Mountaineering'}} value="Mountaineering">Mountaineering</option>
                <option {{selectedSport sport 'Climbing'}} value="Climbing">Climbing</option>
                <option {{selectedSport sport 'Mountain biking'}} value="Mountain biking">Mountain biking</option>
            </select>
            <label for="floatingSelect">Sport</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating col-2">
            <select name="difficulty" class="form-select" id="floatingSelect">
                <option {{selectedDifficulty difficulty 'all'}} value="all">All</option>
                <option {{selectedDifficulty difficulty 'Easy'}} value="Easy">Easy</option>
                <option {{selectedDifficulty difficulty 'Medium'}} value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option {{selectedDifficulty difficulty 'Hard'}} value="Hard">Hard</option>
                <option {{selectedDifficulty difficulty 'Expert'}} value="Expert">Expert</option>
            </select>
            <label for="floatingSelect">Difficulty</label>
        </div>
```

I would like to use the same helper for both of them, but I still don't know how to do it. *(btw, ignore the fact that I should be using an {{#each}} for displaying the options :P)*

The controller:

```
module.exports.list = (req, res, next) => {
const filters = req.query;
const { location, sport, difficulty } = req.query;
const criterial = Object.keys(filters)
    .filter((key => filters[key] !== 'all'))
    .reduce((criterial, filter) => {
        if (filters[filter]) criterial[filter] = filters[filter];
        return criterial;
    }, {});

    Route.find(criterial)
    .then(routes => {
        res.render('routes/list', { routes, location, sport, difficulty })
    })
    .catch(next)
   }
```

The helpers:

```
hbs.registerHelper('selectedSport', (option, sportValue) => {
    return option === sportValue ? ' selected' : '';
})

hbs.registerHelper('selectedDifficulty', (option, difficultyValue) => {
    return option === difficultyValue ? ' selected' : '';
})
```

Many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I think before trying to solve the helper you need to get an otherwise working example. The `sport` and `difficulty` values obviously don't make sense in this template and should represent iteration values. I would get that part working first, then tackle the helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it this way:

Instead of typing all the options directly on the HBS, I create these with a helper that renders each option.

```
        <div class="form-floating col-3">
            <select name="sport" class="form-select" id="floatingSelect">
                {{#each sportOptions as |sportOption|}}
                {{option ../sport sportOption}}
                {{/each}}
            </select>
            <label for="floatingSelect">Sport</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating col-2">
            <select name="difficulty" class="form-select" id="floatingSelect">
                {{#each difficultyOptions as |difficultyOption|}}
                {{option ../difficulty difficultyOption}}
                {{/each}}
            </select>
            <label for="floatingSelect">Difficulty</label>
        </div>
```

The helper receives 2 parameters: sport and sportOption and according to their value, returns a string cointaining the option with the selected attribute or not.

```
hbs.registerHelper('option', function (selectedValue, value) {
    const selectedProperty = value == selectedValue ? 'selected' : '';
    return new hbs.SafeString(`<option value=${value} ${selectedProperty}>${value}</option>`);
  });
```

sportOption and difficultyOption are arrays with all the possibilities inside them.

I hope that, if someone else has the same problem, this can be of any help :)